# Software Updater check UI not working after updating to 22.10

Tags: apt, updates, gui, update-manager, 22.10

Next screenshot with tick selections allows to select/unselect those that are selected (blue). However, you can not interact with the rest.
[image]

In any case, after clicking on "Install Now" all software is updated, it looks like is just an interface issue in "Software Updater".

Have someone experienced something similar? any solution?

Comment: Did you happen to compare the GUI output with the output of `apt list --upgradable`?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your time and answer! Yes, it's different, shall I update those packages as well? I tried with "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" but the those  packages are still there.